# "^" behaviour when typing on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

OS: ubuntu 22.04

The ^ symbol, when typed on a ubuntu 22.04 installation, gets a bar under it and has unique behavior depending on subsequent commands (i.e. 2 raises a number to look aesthetically pleasing for math). How do I remove this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>^</kbd> for you is currently set up as a dead key. Typing it in combination with other characters will produce a unicode character.

This behavior is determined by the keyboard layout you have active. For US keyboards, the layout `English (US, intl., with dead keys)` does that.

*Resolution*: switch to a keyboard behavior that does not have dead keys in "Settings" - "Keyboard".